# Are the Saviors loyal to Negan? Or to any leader of the Saviors?

Tags: the-walking-dead

In the latest episode of *The Walking Dead*, they introduced Negan who is the leader of the Saviors. And he managed to get all our beloved heroes on their knees.

If Rick for example managed to kill Negan while they were all on their knees with a hidden knife or something, would the survivors be loyal to Negan and kill Rick? Or would Rick be their leader then?

Comment: Do you want answers based on Comics or on TV? Because on TV it would be speculation as Negan hasn't been developed yet, but on Comics that's a whole other ballpark

Comment: I can be from either Comic or Tv, I was hesitant to ask for comic, not wanting to add Spoilers for other people.

Comment: I've personally not read the comics, but have gotten a bit of info about some parts, Neegan is a major character over there. But Comics and TV aren't necessarly equal (eg: Daryl is a made up character for TV). So everything that comes out of comics has to be taken with a bit of salt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you said you're OK with the comics...

While the group is fiercely loyal to Negan, and ready to kill or die for him, many are are willing to live under someone else's leadership.

Specifically, in the comics, (possible spoiler warning: many of the plot points from the comics have translated to the show)

> Dwight turns on Negan, and helps defeat him. Dwight then assumes leadership of the Saviors, who begin cooperatively working with the rest of the communities. Not all of the Saviors are happy with the new leadership.

Comment: Ok yes that is more or less what I thought, But Dwight already being a savior has some power amongst them.  Will Rick have the same outcome(People excepting him but not being happy), Or will they just downright kill him?

Comment: Now we're largely getting into speculative territory, but like I mentioned, a lot of the Saviors still don't trust Rick specifically. Still, after the previous war, most *likely* wouldn't try to outright murder him unless they could raise up enough of a militia willing to take on the the communities again.